# How to Make Social Media Album Relational Database which can dispay only specific Friend/people?

Tags: database, database-design, database-connection, relational-database, social-networking

can anyone help me :
how to make album table in Social Media which have visible options Public,Private and for **Specific Friend**/People ? How to make Relational table among album and List of specific friend who can see inside album ?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You need a table to resolve the many to many relationship between People and Album. This table will have a foreign key reference to the PersonID and the AlbumID, and perhaps a boolean value "IsVisible."

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to write up the specification in a way that is easily (or as easily as possible) converted to a schema. Such as:

"This system consists of Users and Albums. An Album is created and owned by one and only one User. The User who owns an Album has complete access to it but all other Users are either denied all access to the Album (the default) or are allowed read access to the Album when given permission by the owning User."

There are two nouns (Users, Albums) in the spec so there are two entities: Users and Albums.

```
create table Users(
  ID    int auto_generating primary key,
  ...   ... -- other user data
);

create table Albums(
  ID    int auto_generating primary key,
  ...   ... -- other album data
);
```

There two significant verbs (Own, Access). These describe the relationship between the entities. As there is one and only one owner, the simplest method is to create a foreign key from the Album to the owning User.

```
create table Albums(
  ID      int auto_generating primary key,
  OwnerID int not null references Users( ID ),
  ...     ... -- other album data
);
```

Allowing access to the albums is simple enough using an intersection table.

```
create table AlbumAccess(
    AlbumID  int not null references Albums( ID ),
    UserID   int not null references Users( ID )
);
```

This table could have other attributes which describe the relationship such as the date the access was granted or, if you wanted to allow temporary access, a "GoodUntil" date. You can get really creative if you need to.

One immediate improvement that comes to mind is if users have a long list of other users they want to grant access, or several such lists. Going through and granting access to all those users every time they create a new album would get tedious quickly. So you could create user lists containing, well, a list of users. Access could then be granted to the list thus to each user in the list.

Each user could create their own list(s) and name them anything they want: "Family", "Fall2017EnglishClass", "Paid Subscribers", etc.

This gives us another entity in the system and thus another table:

```
create table Lists(
  ID      int    auto_generating primary key,
  Name    varchar( 32 ) not null,
  OwnerID int not null references Users
);
```

Okay, but now we have created another problem? (No! That never happens!) The intersection table contains a FK to Users, not Lists. We could create another intersection table tying together albums and lists, but here's another possible solution.

Suppose when we create a new user, we also create, behind the scenes, a list consisting of only that user. When a user is given access to an album, it is actually given to this list alias. Then all access would be through lists.

So we would need to maintain which users were in each list.

```
create table ListMembers(
  ListID    int  not null references Lists( ID ),
  MemberID  int  not null references Users( ID ),
  constraint PK_ListMembers primary key( ListID, MemberID )
);
```

So the UserID field of the AlbumAccess table would be changed to ListID and would reference the Lists table.

This has all been seat-of-the-pants designing, I haven't drawn this out. So there could well be something important I missed. But it should be close enough you can handle any loose ends. If not, ask away.

Comment: Great, I'll do that!

Comment: by the way.. how to vote the answer > why I cannot vote your answered ? when i voted appeared this message "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"..